# iLogger within a class started from Main

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ilogger

struggeling with iLogger. For me it is currently not clear how to instantiate a logging instance aside the web controller.

In main I'm staging a "version monitor":

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebHostEnvironment env;
            VersionMonitor vControl = new VersionMonitor();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();    
        }
```

Within the version monitor constructor I'm starting a timer:

```
public VersionMonitor()
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = UpInterval;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Enabled = true;
         }
```

All I want to do, is now to log sth. within the elapsed timer event:

```
   static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            //how to?
            ILogger<timer_Elapsed> _logger;
            logger.LogInformation("Message");
    }
```

Could you guide me, how to do this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than directly instantiating your class...look into the official hosted services. They should integrate nicely with DI so they get an injected logger. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). They even have examples with timers.

```
public class VersionMonitor: IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    ILogger<VersionMonitor> _logger;
  
    Timer _timer;

    public VersionMonitor(ILogger<VersionMonitor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = UpInterval;
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {        
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Message");
    }

     public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then just wire it up:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();    
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<VersionMonitor>();
        });
```

Comment: Wow, so great. What a cool solution.

Is it also possible to access the running instance of the VersionMonitor anywhere else of the programm code?
Thanks so much.

Comment: @Airwave Why do you need to access it elsewhere? What are you planning to do with it?

Comment: In the class, where the timer is located, I have some other functions, that I partially use in the timer, but that I also want to use in special situations outside the code.

Comment: @Airwave Then that sounds like you need to create another class, that way each of the other classes can refer to it.

Comment: Mhhh, yes thanks, would make most sense :-)